# FullCalendar set DatePicker after set day

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using JQuery FullCalendar with DatePicker. I'm wondering when you change the date in FullCalendar he update the DatePicker, which event should I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you click on a day on the calendar you want to change the date of the DatePicker. You could use the `dayclick` event to accomplish this.

Here is an example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {     
        //update the datepicker here
    }
});
```

The `date` parameter holds a Date object for the current day.

Answer (score 1):

This will change the date of the DatePicker to match the current view of FullCalendar. For example, when the prev, next, or today buttons are clicked.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
viewRender: function(view, element){
        var currentdate = view.intervalStart;
        $('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date(currentdate));

    }

    });
```

Comment: It works, but when I want to render #datepicker, it is displayed twice.